# Calc, formula to find the index of the minimum value

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, is it possible to write a formula which, given a column of unsorted data (see example below), returns the largest index of the minimum value greater than zero? The following almost works:

```
{=MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A16>0,A1:A16)),A1:A16,0)}
```

but it returns an index of 11 instead of 16 with the data shown below.

[image: Histogram data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that all the cells contain integers, you can modify your formula to add a fractional offset to bias the entries. I found that the following works on my test data (I didn't type in all of yours):

```
=MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A16>0,A1:A16+0.9/ROW(A1:A16))),A1:A16+0.9/ROW(A1:A16),0)
```

I filled the first 10 rows with two `1` entries and it found the second `1`, and as I added more rows it returned the last entry whenever I added another `1`. Note that it is a scalar function, so there are no surrounding `{}` braces.

Comment: Entering the function as shown returns a value of 15, but with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` it returns 16 (what I would have expected). Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: I've copied in your data, but I get `16`. I can't see how it would give `15`, unless it was inexplicably including the zero entries (change `A15` to check), and I have no idea what difference `Ctrl+Shift` would make. I'm using version `1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1` on Ubuntu 15.05.

Answer (score 0):

To take what you did and reverse it, create a [User-Defined Basic Function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions#Defining_A_Function_Using_LibreOffice_Basic):

```vb
Function REVERSE_ARRAY(aIn)
    If NOT IsArray(aIn) Then
        REVERSE_ARRAY = "Err:520"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim aOut(LBound(aIn,1) To UBound(aIn,1), _
        LBound(aIn,2) To UBound(aIn,2)) As Single
    Dim i As Integer, reverse_i As Integer
    For i = LBound(aIn,1) to UBound(aIn,1)
        reverse_i = LBound(aIn,1) + UBound(aIn,1) - i
        aOut(reverse_i, 1) = aIn(i, 1)
    Next i
    REVERSE_ARRAY = aOut()
End Function
```

Modify the array function so it says this:

```
17-MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A16>0,A1:A16)),REVERSE_ARRAY(A1:A16),0)
```

In my testing, this approach and @AFH's answer produced the same results.